# How to pass multiple values in htaccess Xampp

Tags: .htaccess

I need to pass multiple values to a variable by first checking the pattern and then we need to pass multiple values
I have used this below code and its only taking %1 value

```
RewriteMap du "prg:C:/xampp/perl/bin/perl.exe C:/xampp/cgi-bin/echo2.pl"
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} accountno=(.*)&username=(.*)&password=(.*)
RewriteCond ${du:%1%2%3} =0
```

I need to check accountno=(.*)&username=(.*)&password=(.*) pattern and if the pattern is satisfied   then we need to pass the values of the accountno,username and password into "du" variable and then I'm checking if the value is 0.
What changes should be made so that i can accept the 3 values at once and pass it to "du" in htaccess.

Comment: Quite unclear what you are trying to do here. What would passing those values _“into "du" variable”_ actually _mean_? Are you trying to generate the variable _name_ dynamically? So for `accountno=A&username=B&password=C`, you would want to access the variable `${du:ABC}` at this point?

Comment: I don’t think you can do actual math at this point - using those back references `%1%2%3` is basically implicit string concatenation, not “addition”. Plus, I still can’t make much sense of this - what values would you be passing for accountno, username and password, that could possibly be combined to a value that would look like “0” afterwards?

Comment: The external program you use as a rewritemap source, only gets _one_ value passed via STDIN. So if you need to pass multiple values, then you need to find a way to combine them into one single value - for example, by separating them with a comma or something. Your external program will then of course have to parse that format into the individual values again.

Answer (score 0):

We just have to use (.*) instead of accountno=(.*)&username=(.*)&password=(.*) then we will get the whole value has string